# Store per user data in sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint

I got to store some user specific data (string) in my Sharepoint webpart.I guess hidden webpart properties should do the trick. Tried with the following attributes on webpart property:

```
[WebBrowsable(false)]
[Bindable(true)]
[WebPartStorage(Storage.Personal)]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
```

But I observe in the webpart that data stored is not user specific. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

How are you reading your data ? You can use the [WebPart.PartCacheRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.partcacheread.aspx) method to retrieve per use values.

web.config can be modified to signal how you want your [WebPartCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585600(office.11).aspx) to be stored. To support caching in database then you must include the [Serializable()] attribute to you custom classes

The [WebPart.EffectiveStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.effectivestorage.aspx) property can also help in determining how the data is stored:

```
if (EffectiveStorage == Storage.Shared)
{
    output.Write("<b>You are now in shared mode.</b>");
}
```

Just wondering why you have WebBrowsable attribute set as false. Are the users not able to configure the web part ? When and how is the property value set ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. I actually have to user selected data from a drop down. This drop selection needs to be retained when user comes back to site. WebBrowsable is set to false because i dont want the user to see the webpart property. Just store the drop down selected value in webpart property

Comment: Just a thought, you could use a property bag from the SPWeb object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413763.aspx) but that's originally thought for complex objects and might be overkill in your case